# Routing in Web Api for Get() method's overload

Tags: c#, routes

I have the following code in my Asp.Net web api controller:

```
class MyController:ApiController
{
    public returntype1 Get(string somevalue)
    {
    }

    public returntype2 Get(string somevalue, int id)
    {
    }
}
```

And the routing method that I have is

```
class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(HttpConfiguration config) 
    {
        var routes = config.Routes;  
        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{somevalue}/{id}",
            defaults: new {action = "Get", somevalue = RouetParameter.optional,id=RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

I have url  for the first Get(string somevalue) method like `/api/My/get?somevalue=hello`

And for second Get(string somevalue, int id) overload like `/api/My/get?somevalue=hello&id=1234`

but I want to make some changes in the routing so that for 1st Get method I can have url like `/api/My/hello`
and for second overload Get method I can have url like `/api/My/hello/1234`

Comment: Your response will be highly appreciated guys. Please try to help me on this one. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Enable Attribute Routing it in WebApiConfig.cs:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
}
```

Your controller can be something like this:

```
public class MyController: ApiController
{
    // Matches the route my/hello
    [Route("my/{somevalue}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public string MethodOne(string somevalue)
    {
        return somevalue;
    }

    // Matches the route my/hello/1234
    [Route("my/{somevalue}/{id}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public int MethodTwo(int id)
    {
        return id;
   }
}
```